# Ionic 3 Volume Key Event Capture

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

What I want to do is call one of my functions whenever the user presses the volume up or the volume down buttons on the phone. What I tried so far is using the cordova events, but without any success (nothing happens when I touch the buttons)

In `app.component.ts`:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", this.myFunc, false);
});

myFunc() {
  console.log("it's working");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [cordova-plugin-volume-buttons](https://github.com/manueldeveloper/cordova-plugin-volume-buttons) plugin

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a Capacitor plugin to solve this. Works on both iOS and Android. If it helps please give it a star!

https://github.com/thiagobrez/capacitor-volume-buttons

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try using cordova-volume-buttons plugin

source :[cordova volume button plugin](https://github.com/manueldeveloper/cordova-plugin-volume-buttons)